# Splitting model instance for serializer into 3 different fields

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

Tom Christie has helped me a bunch in gear me to the right direction of using REST framework, but I have another problem, now:

NOTE: This is using a viewsets.ModelViewSet

In my original code, I can return coordinate JSON data by using zip() with split() on the model instance xyz (which holds coordinate data like "20x40x50").
I called my own toJSON() function to make  JSON-ready ouput of everything i need.
It comes out something like:

```
[
  {
   "id" : "4"
   "x" : "500",
   "Y" : "80",
   "z" : "150"
   "color" : "yellow"
  },
  ...
]
```

The problem with using REST Framework serializers is that I only know how to do the serializers.Field(source"xyz") thing. I do not know how to return "x" "y" "z" as separate fields, instead of return "xyz" as one big field.

Here's my code:

```
serializers.py:
---------------
class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    firstname = serializers.Field(source='owner.first_name')
    lastname = serializers.Field(source='owner.last_name')

    x = ???
    y = ???
    z = ???

class Meta:
    model = Note
    fields = ('id','owner','firstname','lastname','text','color', 'x', 'y, 'z', 'time')
```

And here's the view:

```
    views.py:
    ---------
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = Note.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            serializer = NoteSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            if 'text' in request.GET:
                if self.is_numeric(request.GET['id']) and self.is_numeric(request.GET['x']) and self.is_numeric(request.GET['y']) and self.is_numeric(request.GET['z']):

                    serializer = NoteSerializer(data=request.QUERY_PARAMS)
                    intx = int(float(request.GET['x']))
                    inty = int(float(request.GET['y']))
                    intz = int(float(request.GET['z']))
                    serializer.object.xyz = str(intx) +'x'+ str(inty) +'x'+ str(intz)
                    serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def create(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = NoteSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.object.owner = request.user
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here's my model:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
import json
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Note(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=True)
text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
xyz = models.CharField(max_length=20)
time = models.DateTimeField((u"Note Creation Date and Time"), auto_now_add=True,  blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.owner)
```

Thanks a lot for the help! I'm new to Python/Django/REST. This seems very interesting, but just has been frustrating me for days.

UPDATE:

It seems I cannot access xyz through the views.py with serializer.object.xyz. It says the same error "Nonetype has no attribute xyz"

```
serializer = NoteSerializer(data=request.QUERY_PARAMS)
intx = int(float(request.GET['x']))
inty = int(float(request.GET['y']))
intz = int(float(request.GET['z']))
serializer.object.xyz = str(intx) +'x'+ str(inty) +'x'+ str(intz)
serializer.save()
```

Comment: Are you planning to write those values with api in the same way?

Comment: ^ Well, I mean, I can write it another way, but I was just wondering if it's possible with the REST framework, and if so, what would be the process? It seems like I need to use Custom Fields... but I'm not sure where to start...

Answer (score 2):

You can try sending your x,y,z to the serializer using the [get_serializer_context](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html) so something like...

```
from core import models

from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework import serializers

class BloopModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x_coord = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_x')

    def get_x(self, instance):
        return self.context['x']

    class Meta:
        model = models.Bloop

class BloopAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BloopModelSerializer
    queryset = models.Bloop.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(BloopAPIView, self).get_serializer_context()
        # you have access to self.request here
        context.update({
            'x': 1111,
            'y': 2222
        })

        return context
```

This way you don't have to override the list and create functions anymore.

On a side note, you can also try putting your coords into its own serializer and group them within the serializer. rest_framework can nest serializers, so you can add a `CoordinatesSerializer` class and your Model Serializer would look something like this

```
class CoordinateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    x = models.Field()
    y = models.Field()
    # ...

class BloopModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coordinates = CoordinateSerializer('get_coords')

    def get_coords(self, instance):
        return self.context['coords']

    class Meta:
        model = models.Bloop
```

Comment: Hi jc555! Thanks for all these tips. I never knew about some of these. I'll try them out, and will get back to this if I get it working.

Btw, for the nested serializer, what does get_coords() do here?

Comment: I'm getting a KeyError that says just 'X' from return self.context['x']. Also, for the nested serializers, it seems I cannot do what you did with models.Field(). It just says the models don't have Field().

Comment: The nested serializers is a bit trickier, it expects an object to be passed into it. You will need to pass an object, usually a model object, but dict will work if you use a `SerializerMethodField`. You don't really need nested serializers, it was just a suggestion since I'm not sure of the context of your project and how you wanted to display your JSON.

Comment: Thanks jc555! I'll try it out. I'm still trying to get it working from both answers. I'll post which solution was the best soon! Thanks so much for your help! It definitely led me to a better direction.

Answer (score 2):

My approach on this:

```
COORD = dict(x=0, y=1, z=2)

class CoordinateField(serializers.Field):
    def field_to_native(self, obj, field_name):
        # retrieve and split coordinates
        coor = obj.content.split('x')

        # get coordinate value depending on coordinate key (x,y,z)
        return int(coor[COORD[field_name]])

    def field_from_native(self, data, files, field_name, into):
        into['xyz'] = u'{x}x{y}x{z}'.format(**data)
        super(CoordinateField, self).field_from_native(data, files, field_name, into)

class BloopModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    x = CoordinateField()
    y = CoordinateField()
    z = CoordinateField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bloop
```

and this is what I get as result:

```
{
    "x": 10,
    "y": 20,
    "z": 30,
    "content": "10x20x30"
},
```

**EDIT:**

views.py

```
class BloopList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Bloop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BloopModelSerializer

bloop_list = Bloop.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^api/bloops/$', 'myapp.views.bloop_list', name='bloop-list'),
```

**SUGGESTION**

You should not use list GET method to change/add object, DRF has built-in classes to make it very easy and makes you follow correct REST standards.

For example, your list method takes request data using GET params, which is a bad idea, whenever you update or add new object you should provide data inside request body using POST or PUT. DRF assumes, that is the way data is provided and takes care of everything.

Comment: Ah! Interesting. I was actually on the verge of writing a very similar thing, after checking out Custom fields in the REST Framework. 

I'll go ahead and check this out. Thanks for your help and direction! I'm making this web app for practice, and to learn it. I admit, I'm a noob :P

Comment: Say, in my model I already have an instance called "xyz" that holds the coordinate data like "10x20x30". How would I use "xyz" as "input" for this splitting?

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang Oh you mean field name is "xyz", then instead `coor = obj.content.split('x')` use `coor = obj.xyz.split('x')`.

Comment: Oh! I see the correlation between everything now. I couldn't really get a grasp of the concept of custom fields.
Thanks for the super quick response! I'll go ahead and try it out right now.

Comment: I am now getting an error: "dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 3" when using the COORD = dict part. I'm not too sure what this means?

Comment: Ah I see. Can you kindly explain why it didn't work earlier? (I'm learnin, sorry).

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang I just replaced the first line, so that dict is now correctly created.

Comment: So it seems like when I do coor = obj.content.split('x'), obj returns as an object of <Something: someusername>, which is correct, but says "content" is not an attribute, which is right.

But when I do coor = obj.xyz.split('x'), obj suddenly becomes a Nonetype. What? It just doesn't make sense. How can changing .content to .xyz change the obj type????

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang Please update you post with Note model definition.

Comment: @mariodiv : Hi! I updated my post with my Note model. It's really odd how if I do some bogus attribute like obj.asdf, it shows up correctly as a <Note: someusername> object with no attribyte 'asdf', but if I do obj.xyz, it says 'NoneType" has to attribyte 'xyz'.

I don't get why it suddenly becomes 'NoneType' once I call xyz from it... thanks a lot for your help! It has helped me learn a lot.

Comment: No idea why you have this problem, you can zip the app and send a link to it or somewhere so I can take a look. Otherwise I cannot help.

Comment: It seems StackOverflow doesn't have a messaging thing. Can I email it to you or something? Or, should I provide the code through my own web server (for you to copy and paste)

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang please add your app into dropbox or smth and post the url

Comment: Here's the app itself. (I couldn't really zip it up, but hopefully you (or readers) can load it up. I'm using the NoteViewSet viewset at the bottom of the views.py

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8mlr4succs14axh/MqNi4U3a1r

It's a fairly simple app with nothing really. I'm just trying learn how to manipulate data with Django REST

Comment: I still cannot understand why the object is NoneType. I tried (for fun), doing obj.color, and it returned correctly (Of course, saying how the color isn't an int(), which is norma)

But once I do obj.xyz, it breaks and says "Nonetype has no attribute xyz"... I feel like it's a simple issue, but...vague...

Comment: I figured out the solution to the problem. I will still mark this as the best answer, since I think it's the simplest and a more elegant way to implement the .split() function. jc555's solution could also work, but I think this solution seems more fitting for what the code is intended to do. I will edit your answer to include the solution.

Comment: It seems I am having trouble accessing serializer.object.xyz , with the same Nonetype attribyte error

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang I have updated my post, there you can see I've added `field_from_native` method to my field class, it does the opposite - deserialize provided data into single field value. Also a small comment has been added.

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand how maybe I should use PUT. What function would I use to update the positions, though? I didn't think the create() would be appropriate. Is it the update() or put()?

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang You really need to go through DRF tutorial, you will get the answer, play around, look at the source code.. just take your taime and you will understand the concept.

Comment: So I followed your code, but no matter what I do, I still get "Nonetype has no attribyte xyz". The only way to get pass this is to return None if obj is None. But I don't think that's an elegant way?

Comment: @KevinTomiyoshiYang ok let's take a look, this time, please upload the whole project ok, so I have the same settings etc.

Comment: Here's the whole project called 'notes'. Sorry for the late reply. I'm a college student (was doing homework and projects). Here's the link to it:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rwdtqlr9lo2n59m/mYQmy1EZxJ